# JS - When i change a value of array 'a', to a value of array 'b' the value of 'b' also changes

Tags: javascript, arrays

When i change a value of array 'a', to a value of array 'b' the value of 'b' also changes.
I have no idea why.

```
 const a = [
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
    ["NICKEL", 0.05],
    ["DIME", 0.1],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25],
    ["ONE", 1],
    ["FIVE", 5],
    ["TEN", 10],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
  ];

  var b = [];


  b.unshift(a[3]);
  //The value of a[3][1] changes to the value of b[0][1]!!!
  b[0][1] += a[3][1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not copied the array, but referenced it.

Unlike other variables, when you set another variable equal to an array (or object), the original array is referenced, instead of *copied*.

```
var x = 2
var y = x; // x is COPIED
y += 1;
console.log(x); // x = 2
console.log(y); // y = 3
```

---

```
var x = [2]
var y = x; // x is REFERENCED
y[0] += 1;
console.log(x); // x = [3] - not x = [2]
console.log(y); // y = [3]
```

`x` and `y` refer to the same underlying array.

---

A quick way to copy the array is to call the `slice` method with no arguments (slicing the entire array).

```
var x = [2]
var y = x.slice(); // x is COPIED
y[0] += 1;
console.log(x); // x = [2]
console.log(y); // y = [3]
```

---

As [Ricardo Rocha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62252496/13683188) shows, there are other ways to copy the array.

In general, you can perform shallow or *deep* copying. The above is shallow copying, where you only transfer each element in the original array to the copy array. If the elements in the array are other objects (like a nested array), you may get the same problem when editing them (as they're still references to the objects in the original, not copies) - here you would want to do a *deep copy*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @user3272507 I added some more information you may want to know about

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you write something like "`array1 = array2`", it's not the value of the array that is saved but the reference. You have to use "`[...array]`" to dopy the value and not the reference.

```js
 const a = [
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
    ["NICKEL", 0.05],
    ["DIME", 0.1],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25],
    ["ONE", 1],
    ["FIVE", 5],
    ["TEN", 10],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
  ];

  var b = [];

  b.unshift([...a[3]]);
  b[0][1] += a[3][1];
  console.log(b)
  console.log(a)
```

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that the spread operator only does a _shallow_ clone. You would have the same problem with `var a = [[0,1],[0,2]]` and `var b = [...a]`.

Answer (score 0):

It 's because arrays are [referece types](https://www.dyn-web.com/javascript/arrays/value-vs-reference.php) in javascript.

You have primitive types like number, string, or booleans. Then you have reference types like arrays or objects.

From [here](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0#:~:text=Javascript%20has%205%20data%20types,to%20them%20collectively%20as%20Objects.), you can get a good explanation of what is reference types in javascript:

> Variables that are assigned a non-primitive value are given a reference to that value. That reference points to the object’s location in memory. The variables don’t actually contain the value.

For the case of arrays, you can simply copy "as value" like [this](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/35-es6-way-to-clone-an-array/):

```js
const original = [1,2,3,4];
const clone = [...original];
clone[0] = 20;
console.log(clone);
```

Or you can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const original = [1,2,3,4];
const clone = Array.from(original);
clone[0] = 20;
console.log(clone);
```